# In a coin flip experiment, what if the probability of success has a distribution other than delta function

Tags: st.statistics

Note: this question came up in a research problem; that is why I thought asking in here would be more appropriate. If not, please let me know.

Let $\chi$ be a random variable that characterizes the time required for an event to happen since the last event.

For example, the event might be taking step forward, and if $\chi$ has a distribution peaked around $1$, then in average, at each second, I will take a step forward.

**Question:**

For a given fixed time $T$, what is the probability distribution of # of number events happens between $t = 0$ and $t = T$.

---

This is like construction of binomial distribution, but in that case, the probability of an event to happen is a fixed value $p$; the distribution is a delta function at $p$. However, in this case, this distribution can be any arbitrary distribution (to illustrate the point, you can assume it is Gaussian).

Comment: Thanks for the no-comment down vote!

Answer (score 1):

The basic observation is that
$$P(\#\ge k)=P(Y_k:=\sum^k X_i\le T)$$ where $X_i$ are your independent Gaussians $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ (not really an appropriate assumption since they can be negative, but it's kind of okay if $\mu$ is large and $\sigma^2$ small).

$Y_k$ is itself Gaussian $N(k\mu,k\sigma^2)$. And so let $Z=(Y-k\mu)/(\sigma\sqrt{k})$; it has the standard normal cdf $\Phi$, and
$$P(\#\le k)=1-\Phi((T-k\mu)/(\sigma\sqrt{k})).$$
So the pmf $P(\#=k)$ is approximately 
$$
[1-\Phi((T-k\mu)/(\sigma\sqrt{k}))]
-
[1-\Phi((T-(k-1)\mu)/(\sigma\sqrt{k-1}))]
$$
$$
=-\Phi((T-k\mu)/(\sigma\sqrt{k}))
+\Phi((T-(k-1)\mu)/(\sigma\sqrt{k-1}))
$$

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly, in the case where $X_i$s are not Gaussian r.v, then first I would need to find what is the probability distribution of $Y_k$ for every $k$. Then, I would need to construct cdf of $Y$, and find $P(# = k)$ by considering the difference between $cdf(k) - cdf(k-1)$, right ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas yes... the famous example is the exponential distribution where the answer turns out to be the Poisson distribution